# Under what conditions $J^{T}J$ equals to the Hessian?

Tags: jacobian, quadratic-programming, hessian-matrix

The title says it all but for some context:

In robotics the Jacobian maps a robot's joint velocities to the velocities at its end-point.

In *some* quadratic programming approaches (again in the robotics context) the Hessian is considered as $\mathbf{H}=J^TJ$. Note that in our field often $J\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, n > m$.

My question is, under what conditions $\mathbf{H}=J^TJ$ holds or is a valid approximation. I've seen papers that say this notion isn't valid in some cases.

Comment: What is the definition of Hessian? Is it the matrix of second derivatives? If that is the case, what is the map to differentiate?

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349026 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2733257